# How can I add * in the middle of the box that is created by this bash script?

Tags: scripting

How can I add a `*` into the middle of the box that is created by this bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# raami joonistamine
echo -n "sisesta ridade arv: "
read rida
echo -n "sisesta tärnide arv: "
read tarn
# genereeri rea numbrid
for ((i = 1; i <= $rida;i++))
do
    echo -n "$i "
    # kui on esimene või viimane rida
    if [ $i -eq 1 -o $i -eq $rida ]; then
    # tärnidest tulev rida
    for((j = 1; j <=$tarn; j++))
    do
        echo -n "* "
    done
# teised read
    else
        echo -n "* "
        # tühikud
        for((j = 2; j < $tarn;j++))
        do
            echo -n "  "
        done
    echo -n "* "
    fi
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your innermost loop:

```
# tühikud
for((j = 2; j < $tarn;j++))
do
    echo -n "  "
done
```

to

```
# tühikud
for((j = 2; j < $tarn;j++))
do
    if [ "$i" -eq "$(( (rida+1) / 2 ))" ] && [ "$j" -eq "$(( (tarn+1) / 2 ))" ]; then
        echo -n '* '
    else
        echo -n "  "
    fi
done
```

That is, when you detect that you are about to output the middle-most character, insert a `*` instead of a space.

For a slightly more precise placement in the row:

```
# tühikud
for((j = 2; j < $tarn;j++))
do
    if [ "$i" -eq "$(( (rida+1) / 2 ))" ] && [ "$j" -eq "$(( (tarn+1) / 2 ))" ]; then
        if [ "$(( tarn%2 ))" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo -n ' *'
        else
            echo -n '* '
        fi
    else
        echo -n "  "
    fi
done
```

---

Rather than outputting single characters, output a whole row at once.  This is more efficient, and you only have three types of rows to care about: top/bottom rows, middle row, and other rows:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p 'Height: ' rows
read -r -p 'Width : ' cols

topbottom=$( yes '*' | head -n "$cols" | tr '\n' ' ' )
printf -v midrow '*%*s*%*s*' "$(( cols - 2 ))" "" "$(( cols - 2 ))" ""
printf -v otherrows '*%*s*' "$(( 2*(cols - 2) + 1 ))" ""

for (( row = 0; row < rows; ++row )); do

    if (( row == 0 )) || (( row == rows - 1 )); then
        thisrow=$topbottom
    elif (( row == rows / 2 )); then
        thisrow=$midrow
    else
        thisrow=$otherrows
    fi

    printf '%2d %s\n' "$(( ++n ))" "$thisrow"
done
```