# How can I print a hollow rectangle star pattern?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to print the hollow rectangle star pattern but I get an unexpected result.

[image]

```
rows=3
cols=5
       for ((i=1; i<=rows; i++))
         do 
            for ((j=1; j<=cols; j++))
             do
               if ((i==1 || i==rows) || (j==1 || j==cols))
                 then
                    echo "*"
                 else
                   echo " ";
               fi 
             done
            echo;
        done
```

Comment: Related, if not a dupe, from last year: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446614

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. `echo` adds a newline after each output. Try using `echo -n` in bash, or `printf`.
2. The condition is wrong. What you need is to remove the inner parentheses:

   ```
   if ((i==1 || i==rows || j==1 || j==cols))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method and it worked fine

command

```
for i in {1..6}; do echo "*"; done| paste -s; for i in {1..4}; do echo "* *"| awk '{printf "%s%40s\n",$1,$2}'; done;for i in {1..6};do echo "*";done| paste -s


output

for i in {1..6}; do echo "*"; done| paste -s; for i in {1..4}; do echo "* *"| awk '{printf "%s%40s\n",$1,$2}'; done;for i in {1..6};do echo "*";done| paste -s

*   *   *   *   *   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
*   *   *   *   *   *
```