# Draw a rectangle in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the sizeof the rectangle"
read size
clear
for (( i = 1; i <= size; i++ )); do
for (( j = 1; j <= size; j++ )); do
if [ "$i" == 1 ] || [ "$i" == "$size" ] || [ "$j" == 1 ] || [ "$j" == "$size" ]
then
#statements
tput cup $i $j
echo "*"
fi
done
done
```

How can I change the code on line 10 so it uses `echo` instead of `tput cup`? I am using Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need. What should this echo do? What output are you expecting?

Comment: I want to draw rectangle

Comment: Yes, but what do you want the `echo` to do? Why do you want echo? You already have a working script, and you are using a good solution.

Comment: Notably, tput will only work directly on the terminal. If the exercise requires that the result can be redirected to a file (for an automated course or as part of a larger script), then some echo/printf solution is required. Also, the OP solution is seriously sub-optimal for the top and bottom lines: it does an 8-byte cursor move for every *.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Size: ' sz

topbottom=$(yes '*' | head -n "$sz" | tr -d '\n' )
printf -v midrows '*%*s*' "$((sz-2))" ""

printf '%s\n' "$topbottom"
yes "$midrows" | head -n "$((sz-2))"
printf '%s\n' "$topbottom"
```

This computes the top and bottom rows (they are the same), and then the middle rows (these are also the same). Output of the top and bottom rows is then done with two `printf` calls, and the middle rows are outputted by the `yes` utility (truncated to the correct number of lines).

The cryptic `*%*s*` format in the `printf` call means "an `*`, a string of width given by the next argument, and then another `*`".  The width is the given size of the rectangle, minus 2, and the string is an empty string (it will be padded with spaces).

Similar questions:

- [How can I print a hollow rectangle star pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505671/how-can-i-print-a-hollow-rectangle-star-pattern)
- [How do i make this script print out multiple boxes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446614/how-do-i-make-this-script-print-out-multiple-boxes)
- [How can I add * in the middle of the box that is created by this bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445911/how-can-i-add-in-the-middle-of-the-box-that-is-created-by-this-bash-script)
- [Draw triangle on the console in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578700/draw-triangle-on-the-console-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

if your target does not provide `tput` you could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter the size of the rectangle: " size
clear
for (( i = 1; i <= size; i++ )); do
  for (( j = 1; j <= size; j++ )); do
    if (( 1 == i || size == i || 1 == j || size == j )); then
      echo -n "*"
    else
      echo -n " "
    fi
  done
  echo
done
```

Otherwise your already implemented solution would be fine.

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 1):

This does the whole thing in bash built-ins: no need for yes, head, tr, tput, or nested loops.

```
Paul--) cat ./myBox
#! /bin/bash

sz=$(( ${1:-10} - 2 ))

printf -v xBlk '%-*s' ${sz} ''
xAst="${xBlk//?/*}"
xRow="${xAst//?/ x}"

printf '*%s*\n' "${xAst}"
for r in ${xRow}; do printf '*%s*\n' "${xBlk}"; done
printf '*%s*\n' "${xAst}"

Paul--) ./myBox 5
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
Paul--)
```

Comment: Even nicer if you change the asterisks: in xAst to -; in short printfs to +; in long printf to |;