# Draw triangle on the console in bash

Tags: bash

I want to draw a triangle using nested loops in `bash`, like the following:

```
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/________\
```

Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Enter depth of pyramid: " n
echo "You enetered level: $n"
s=0
space=n
for((i=1;i<=n;i++))
do
  space=$((space-1)) #calculate how many spaces should be printed before /
  for((j=1;j<=space;j++))
  do
    echo -n " " #print spaces on the same line before printing /
  done
  for((k=1;k<=i;k++))
  do
    if ((i==1))
    then
      echo -n "/\ " #print /\ on the same line
      echo -n " " #print space after /\ on the same line
    elif((k==1))
    then
      echo -n "/" #print / on the same line
    elif((k==i))
    then
      for((l=1;l<=k+s;l++))
      do
        echo -n " " #print spaces on the same line before printing /\
      done
      s=$((s+1)) #as pyramid expands at bottom, so we need to recalculate inner spaces
      echo -n "\ " #print \ on the same line
    fi
  done
  echo -e #print new line after each row
done
```

Please help me to find short version.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/505671/5132 .

Comment: This is the second _I have a script that clearly does what I want, please help me!_, with only vague indications of what the help required is, question today.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578665/5132 .

Comment: Tip: Why is the tip a special case? Does it have to be? Is the `/` after the initial spaces conditional? Do you need loop `l`, if you remove the code that cripples loop `k`. Also with better names you can remove the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./script.sh
Size: 5
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/________\
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Size: ' sz

for (( i = 0; i < sz-1; ++i )); do
        printf '%*s/%*s\\\n' "$((sz-i-1))" "" "$((2*i))" ""
done

if [[ $sz -gt 1 ]]; then
        printf '/%s\\\n' "$( yes '_' | head -n "$((2*i))" | tr -d '\n' )"
fi
```

I chose *not* to use nested loops as it would be slow an unnecessary. Each bit of the triangle is instead printed using `printf` with a format specifying the spacing between the `/` and `\` characters based on the current row `i`.

The bottom row is special and will only be printed if the size of the triangle allows it.

Similar questions:

- [How can I print a hollow rectangle star pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505671/how-can-i-print-a-hollow-rectangle-star-pattern)
- [How do i make this script print out multiple boxes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446614/how-do-i-make-this-script-print-out-multiple-boxes)
- [How can I add * in the middle of the box that is created by this bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445911/how-can-i-add-in-the-middle-of-the-box-that-is-created-by-this-bash-script)
- [Draw a rectangle in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578665/draw-a-rectangle-in-bash/578685#578685)

Comment: Wrote the myTri to go with myBox on the earlier post. TIL this is valid: `for (( c = sz - 1, d = 0; c > 0; c--, d += 2)); do`. Six lines work for me, too, and without external processes like yes, head, tr.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. Note better variable names, quoted variables, No special case, no variable-mutation (except loop counters), no comments explaining **what** the code does(that is the codes job, comments should explain why, or fill in weaknesses in the language), and less loops.

```
#!/bin/bash
if (($# == 0))
then
    read -r -p "Enter depth of pyramid: " requested_height
elif (($# == 1))
then
    requested_height="$1"
fi
echo "You enetered level: $requested_height"

left_edge="/"
right_edge=\\

#this procedure can be replaced by printf, but shown here to
#demonstrate what to do if a built in does not already exist.
function draw_padding() {
    width="$1"
    for((i=1;i<=width;i++))
    do
        echo -n " "
    done
}

for((line_number=1;line_number<=requested_height;line_number++))
do
    initial_spaces=$((requested_height-line_number))
    draw_padding "$initial_spaces"

    echo -n "$left_edge"

    middle_spaces="$(((line_number-1) * 2  ))"
    draw_padding "$middle_spaces"

    echo "$right_edge"

done
```

What did I do: 
 - Indent the code, and name stuff well, so that I can read it.
 - Ask what is conditional: **ALL** lines have a `/` and a `\`, so what changes: the spaces before, and the spaces between.

Note it is not finish, according to the original spec.
And if this is an assignment, them practice some more. If you don't you will hit a wall latter in the course. Today, write this program 3 times without looking at this or previous attempts. Then do it once for each of the next 3 days, then again in a week. Keep practising similar coding challenges (it is like learning to play guitar, you have to practice.)

Comment: But try not to use variable names like E A D G B E.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant que?

Comment: Accumulated experience -- message to self: (a) Don't use upper-case and short names -- often duplicate reserved words, and hard to follow. (b) Standard classical guitar tuning -- useful for strings. (c) Part of practice is to discover, by experience, idioms and techniques that can be applied to a range of problems, are reliable, and are easily adaptable. (d) Don't post jokes.